# Python ctypes with io.readinto doesn't work well

Tags: python, ctypes

When I read binary data with ctypes, it didn't work correctly.

The Binary data

```
03 00 00 00 49 7B 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

THe python code

```
from ctypes import *

class DataStructure(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("long1", c_ulong),
        #("long2", c_ulong),
        ("longlong", c_ulonglong)
    ]

binaryfile = "./ULongLong"
f = open(binaryfile, "rb")

mystruct = DataStructure()
f.readinto(mystruct)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print mystruct.long1
    #print mystruct.long2
    print mystruct.longlong
```

The result

```
3
0
```

But when I read binary data blow instead and uncomment the python code, it worked fine.

```
03 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 49 7B 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

The result

```
3
3
31561
```

It seems like a bug. Could anybody help me to solve this?
Any suggestion will be so much appreciated.

Environment:
Windows 7 x64
Python 2.7 x32
ctypes 1.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you're have trouble with [structure packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/). It looks like your code is reading "03 00 00 00 49 7B 00 00" (word size - 64bits) but only using the first 4 bytes "03 00 00 00".

**Update:** According to [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185502/python-ctypes-with-io-readinto-doesnt-work-well/24187708#comment37338362_24187708), the analysis above is correct. Just set  `_pack_ = 1` in the definition of DataStructure.

Some experimenting with C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct data_structure {
    uint32_t long1;
    uint64_t longlong;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE *fd, *other_fd;
    struct data_structure my_struct;

    my_struct.long1 = 3;
    my_struct.longlong = 31561;

    fd = fopen("ULongLong", "wb");
    if (!fd)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file!");
        return 1;
    }

    fwrite(&my_struct, sizeof(struct data_structure), 1, fd);
    fclose(fd);
    exit(0);
}
```

After compiling and running, inspected the `ULongLong` file:

```
$ hexdump ULongLong
00000000 0300 0000 0000 0000  497b 0000 0000 0000
00000010
```

Sometimes you can get some garbage in the 5th to 8th byte:

```
$ hexdump ULongLong
00000000 0300 0000 ff7f 0000  497b 0000 0000 0000
00000010

$ hexdump ULongLong
0000000 0003 0000 7fff 0000 7b49 0000 0000 0000
0000010
```

<strike>Is this binary file correct?</strike>

Comment: On Windows, ctypes aligns the struct to 8 bytes. Check `ctypes.alignment(mystruct)`. Please add that the solution is to set `_pack_ = 1` in the definition of `DataStructure`.